# Error DataAnnotations deserializando JSON C# (BigInteger to long)

Tags: c#, json, deserialize, dataannotations

Tengo un JSON que estoy deserializando del siguiente tipo

```
{
"dato1": 10160734961016073496,
"dato2": 123,
"dato3": 456,
}
```

Necesito validar que los campos recibidos no exceden cierta longitud, así que estoy utilizando DataAnnotations. He intentado utilizar varios así (no todos al mismo tiempo, aclaro):

```
[MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} excede longitud permitida")]
[Range(typeof(long), "0", "12", ErrorMessage ="El campo {0} excede longitud permitida")] 
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{1,12}$", ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} excede longitud permitida")]

public long dato1{ get; set; }
```

Pero siempre estoy recibiendo el siguiente error ("Can not convert from BigInteger to System.Int64") debido a que no puede convertir el tipo que esta recibiendo (BigInteger en System.Int64(que es lo mismo que un long) ), lo cual al parecer esta intentando hacer durante las validaciones de DataAnnotations:

```
{
  "input.xxx": {
    "_errors": [
      {
        "<Exception>k__BackingField": {
          "ClassName": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
          "Message": "Error converting value 10160734961016073496 to type 'System.Int64'. Path 'xxx.dato1', line X, position XX.",
          "Data": null,
          "InnerException": {
            "ClassName": "System.InvalidOperationException",
            "Message": "Can not convert from BigInteger to System.Int64.",
            "Data": null,
            "InnerException": {
              "ClassName": "System.OverflowException",
              "Message": "Valor demasiado grande o demasiado pequeño para Int64.",
              "Data": null,
              "InnerException": null,
              "HelpURL": null,
              "StackTraceString": "   en System.Numerics.BigInteger.op_Explicit(BigInteger value)\r\n   en Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.FromBigInteger(BigInteger i, Type targetType)",
              "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
              "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
              "ExceptionMethod": "8\nop_Explicit\nSystem.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Numerics.BigInteger\nInt64 op_Explicit(System.Numerics.BigInteger)",
              "HResult": -2146233066,
              "Source": "System.Numerics",
              "WatsonBuckets": null
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer esta validación con alguna validación nativa? Tal vez DataAnnotations para tipos long (He buscado pero no veo que existan para este caso en particular) o algo similar? Algo que no requiera una validación custom? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es porque tú json es un int y estás tratando deserializar en otro formato que es long, para validar la cantidad de datos igual puedes usar regex `[RegularExpression("([0-9]+)")] ` o usar un int.maxvlaue `[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid integer Number")]`